# VS2013 column widths on quickwatch window

Tags: visual-studio-2013

When I open the quickwatch window in Visual Studio 2013, the window opens to the size I set it to previously.  But the columns default so that the Type column is barely visible.  It's very annoying to continually have to resize the columns to see the type.

Is there any VS setting that will keep the column width that the user prefers?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

No. It's been an open issue since VS 2010 and still not fixed in VS 2015.

It seems the VS guys are just not interested.